# Regex pattern to match phone number extension

Tags: regex

I’m trying to match extension of phone numbers. It seems to work fine for so many cases, but this fails for some reason. I can’t figure out why.

Pattern:

```
/^(\d)?[^\d]*?(\d{3}).*?(\d{3}).*?(\d{4}).*(\d{0,6}).*/
```

Phone value:

```
4012538900 (227)
```

It doesn’t match `227` for some reason. If I change my `\d{0,6}` to `\d{3}`, it seems to be ok, same with using range `\d{1,x}` (x > 1). That, of course, will break my other values so it’s not a solution.

[RegEx101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sV2cG9/4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to fix your problem:

```
^(\d)?\D*?(\d{3})\D*(\d{3})\D*(\d{4})\D*(\d{0,6})
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sV2cG9/5)

Avoid using `.*` in your regex since it can also consume your digits, better to use `\D*` for matching non-digits.

Comment: Thank you, this is indeed better and I'll be using it instead. I'd still like to know why regex doesn't match my pattern though.

Comment: first .* matches " (", \d{0,6} should match 227, and the second .* should match ")". I do understand using not digits (^D) is better and I ll be using that from now on. And I understand .* is consuming my digits, but why is it doing it and not matching the \d

Comment: No, @PenguinSource, that's not what it will do. For `.*(\d{0,6}).*/`, the first `.*` will match the rest of the string because it is greedy. Then `(\d{0,6})` will match 0 digits, and then `.*` will match 0 characters.

Comment: @PenguinSource: Because `.*` is greedy and will consume as much as possible before `\d{0,6}` which can also match 0 occurrences of a digit hence that is empty. You could also use `^(\d)?[^\d]*?(\d{3}).*?(\d{3}).*?(\d{4}).*?(\d{1,6})` to make it work.

Comment: I understand that the .* is consuming the digits, ergo not letting the \d match my '227'. I guess it looks and sees that the range goes from 0 to 6 and it just ignores the \d pattern overall (.* eats the \d{0,6}). 

Ok that makes sense, thanks to both.